# AWS Codedeploy when Autoscaling Group set to 0 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I'm using Codedeploy to push to my ec2 instances within an auto scaling group.  At times, that auto scaling group doesn't have any existing instances running.  When I deploy in that situation, codedeploy ALWAYS fails, even though I've set the minimum healthy hosts to 0 instances.

Is there anyway I can get code deploy to say "success" when there are 0 instances?

It appears when codedeploy fails, it doesn't update the revision.  This is a real pain in my situation.

Comment: Any workaround for this rather increasing instance count to 1 before triggering the code deploy job?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have at least a single instance in your deployment group for the deployment to succeed. After you hook the Autoscaling group (containing at least 1 instance) with CodeDeploy, you should do a successful deployment to update the target revision of the deployment group. After this, any new instance scale up should automatically pick up the target revision.

You could also set the :min property of your autoscaling group to 1 to always keep a single instance in it.

Comment: Thanks for this info! Do you know of any documentation for this "automatic CodeDeploy only is done after at least one successful explicit CodeDeploy within the ASG" behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been over two years, but I faced this same issue. My workaround was creating my own Lifecycle Hook for my Auto Scaling Group and an SNS + Lambda for deploying my revisions.

The catch is, you should first Register a Revision for the application without deploying it. As soon as a new instance is created by the Auto Scaling Group the hook will send an SNS message to the Lambda and then you can (based on the message received + Environment variables) look for revisions (already created) and deploy them to the new instances.

I've linked all this by using CloudFormation - which I extremely recommend for this workaround and all other AWS related services.